# How to get dynamic rows but fixed columns by using ngFor in Angular2

Tags: angular2-directives

I have a list of objects that I want to show in a grid of rows and columns using angular2 *ngFor

My requirement is that I want to show 6 columns and dynamic number of rows based on the number of objects in my list.
Ex: If my list has 24 objects then I want to display 4 rows and 6 columns
    If my list has 30 objects then I want to display 5 rows and 6 columns

Please help.